# Programming with classes and databases

Tags: database, oop

Philosophical question here
When it comes to OOP and databases, specifically, programs where the classes are backed up with databases, what is the best way to approach this? For instance, a team class might have a collection of players. The program would just load all of the team data from the database at startup, do all the manipulation in memory, and then write the database at close. Or is it better to write each data manipulation to the database as changes occur? And if this is the better way, why load the data into memory in the first place?

The other concern is that it seems to me that databases break standard OOP in one important way. With my team class with the collection of players, using OOP, the player class would not need to have a property to hold the team name. The player would get the team name from the team class of which it is a member. Now, to save the player in the database, each player record will have to have a column for the team name (or team id, but that's the same thing).

In other words, if you needed a GetAllPlayers() method, would you make it a member method in the team class, to return from memory all of the players in the collection, or make a static method in the player class to get all of the players from the database?

Anyone got any tips on how to answer these questions?

It's been a while since I have taken a programming class. Anyone know of a good text book that goes into understanding the best approach here?

Comment: Take a look at Hibernate /NHibernate. They try to solve exactly this kind of problems. It is not perfect, it is no simple thing. There you can see how complex it is to write OO code based on relational databases.

Answer (score 2):

Databases break object-orientation in a much more fundamental way.  (Or objects break the relational model.  It depends on whether you're a middle tier OO person or a DBA.)

Relational databases are set based by definition, declarative in nature.  Object-oriented languages are object-instance based.  Making the two work together is difficult because of "object-relational impedance mismatch".   This is why you see so many ORM solutions (e.g. TopLink, Hibernate, etc.)  All of them are trying to fool object-oriented programmers into thinking that they only need deal with objects and not worry about relational databases.

However you implement it, I think persistence should be separate from model objects.  I usually put relational code in an interface-based data access layer.  That way model objects don't have to know whether or not they're persisted, and I isolate the CRUD operations in a single package.

As for recommended reading, I'll offer Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) for your consideration.

Comment: I had not heard the term "object-relational impedance mismatch". I do see a good bit about it on the web, which will help. I do like your idea about pulling all of the persistence stuff out. I've always hated having that code in my classes. +1, but I am going to leave it unanswered for a bit to see what other comments come in.

Comment: That's fine.  Good luck with your hunting.

Comment: Of course not impossible.  Nobody said it was.  There are many, many successful systems that use relational databases with objects on the middle tier.  Who said impossible?  Please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this scenario really depends on a huge number of variables.  Typically, a "layered" approach is considered the best bang for your buck in OO languages, but even that has a nearly infinite number of permutations based on the priority of each concern the application must address.

Your representational objects (Player, Team, etc.) should typically not be involved in database operations, as that responsibility would belong to your data access layer, for example.

A good way to approach learning the object-oriented mindset is to take a look at some design patterns.  A good "easy read" book on that topic that I recommend is "Head First Design Patterns."  It's in Java, and gives a variety of angles on each topic it covers.  In my opinion, it serves as a good bridge between the level of the  "Dummies" books and the level of the more abstract/theoretical books.